# Have status bar visible in full screen mode Ionic for android and iOS

Tags: android, css, typescript, cordova, ionic-framework

Hey I am working on an application using Ionic/Cordova and I was wondering if there is a way to allow the application to be in full screen mode and also to be able to show the status bar ?

I am currently using this in my config.xml file:

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Full screen mode is explicitly described as hiding the system bars. Here is the android documentation: https://developer.android.com/training/system-ui/immersive Also you forgot to add your config.xml file. If you want to show the status bar, the best course of action would be to simply not use full screen mode.

Comment: alright I see coz the issue I was facing was when the keyboard layout came up it would push the tabs up when I wanted it to auto hide when keyboard was used.

Answer (score 1):

```
if (ionic.Platform.isAndroid()) {
     window.addEventListener("native.hidekeyboard", function () { 
     StatusBar.hide();
     window.AndroidFullScreen.immersiveMode(false, false);
       });}
```

put this code in app.js in `$ionicPlatform.ready`.

Comment: sorry but I am quite new at this, I don't have a js file in my project , I have a app.component.ts file if that's what you mean ?

Comment: What are the versions of Cordova and Ionic you are using?

Comment: for further you can check this link:https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-statusbar

Comment: cli packages: (/usr/local/lib/node_modules)

    @ionic/cli-utils  : 1.19.2
    ionic (Ionic CLI) : 3.20.0

global packages:

    cordova (Cordova CLI) : 8.0.0

local packages:

    @ionic/app-scripts : 3.1.9
    Cordova Platforms  : android 7.0.0 ios 4.5.4
    Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.9.2